# How to do IF...ELSE like programming in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I do IF..Else like programming in T-SQL?

For example:

```
SELECT YEAR FROM TABLE;
IF (YEAR =  2015)
{ // do something }
ELSE IF (YEAR = 2016)
{ // do something }
```

I am trying to achieve this with stored procedure.

Suggestions are welcome ..as I am newbie to the programming world..

Comment: How about using some CASE WHEN?

Comment: Thanx for your quick response but I have tried it with CASE WHEN as well but got syntax error ..could you Please Provide some Example with this approach

Comment: Put the `if` before the `select`.

Comment: What are the "do something"s? Show example data and desired results.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx for some example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to **store** that value you fetch from the table into a **variable** and then decide on that variable's value:

```
DECLARE @CurrYear INT;

SELECT @CurrYear = YEAR 
FROM TABLE;

IF (@CurrYear =  2015)
     -- do something
ELSE IF (@CurrYear = 2016)
     -- do something else
```

Comment: @MartinSmith: yes, that would be a requirement - and the column `YEAR` would have to be of datatype `INT`, too ....

Comment: Hi @marc_s what if i have multiple values for year in Table. i have tried taking a cursor but i have no clue how can i use IF ..ELSE IF condition inside cursor

Answer (score 0):

As the question was edited before I added this answer, I did not know before that the OP was pointing at T-SQL. Yet, I will leave this here just for people that are interested how it could look in MySQL.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE Years ( yr INT ) 
  BEGIN 
    IF yr = 2015 THEN
      SELECT or whatever ...;
    ELSEIF yr = 2016 THEN
       DO something else...;
    END IF;
  END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: ? He edited his Question mentioned T-SQL aftwerwards, how can I know before. I'll just let this stay here for people who might want to know how in MySQL